# Python check if file exists doesnt work although the file DO exists

Tags: python, flask

i am writing an application in Flask and at some point I want to start some process (quick process) and then check if there is output on the server. If there is - download it, if not - show approprieate communicate.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, g, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# Config
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database/records.db'),
    DEBUG = True,
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads',
    OUTPUT_FOLDER = 'outputs',
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'gro', 'doc', 'docx'])
    ))

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

def run_calculations(filename):
    subprocess.call(['python', os.path.join(app.root_path, 'topologia.py'), 'uploads/' + filename])

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/outputs/<filename>')
def calculated_record(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['OUTPUT_FOLDER'], filename)

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    with app.app_context():
        cur = get_db().cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO records(calculated) VALUES(0)')
        file_id = cur.lastrowid
        get_db().commit()
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        input_file = str(file_id) +'.'+file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], input_file))
        run_calculations(input_file)
        output_name = '/outputs/topologia_wynik' + str(file_id) + '.top'
        if os.path.isfile(output_name):
            return redirect(output_name)
        else:
            return 'Your file is beeing loaded'
    else:
        return "Something went wrong, check if your file is in right format ('txt', 'gro', 'doc', 'docx')"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My whole problem is in this part of code:

```
            if os.path.isfile(output_name):
                return redirect(output_name)
            else:
                return 'Your file is beeing loaded'
```

Because if is never true... When I delete this part of code and redirect to output file without checking it all works fine... Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably `/` in the beginning of `'/outputs/topologia_wynik' + str(file_id) + '.top'`. It means "outputs" folder should be under the root folder, and in your case it seems to be under the server working directory.

Why not pass `os.path.join(app.config['OUTPUT_FOLDER'], 'topologia_wynik' + str(file_id) + '.top')` to `os.path.isfile()` as you did with the input file name?

Comment: Aww you are right! Silly me :D I created this config output_folder and I have never used it. Thank you :)

Comment: Now I added os.spawnl instead of subprocess.call() and the problem is present again... Do you know why it might happen?

Comment: Did you check that the output was actually created? `os.spawnl` takes command line parameters as separate arguments, while `os.spawnv` takes list of parameters as an argument. You passed list to `subprocess.call` so if you did not change it, that might be the issue.

Comment: I changed it the right way, output is created but I noticed that there was a little delay in creating output. Maybe this is the reason

Comment: Did you pass `P_WAIT` as the first argument to `os.spawnl`? In such case, the call would not return until the process exited.

Comment: Thank you, I will do it the other way then